# testing Multiple classnames using enzyme/jest

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

The classes for my component are generated dynamically using CSS Modules. They end up looking something like this:

```
<a class="ScrollArea__scrollArea___HQjeV isOverflown  TMwDC"></a>
```

In certain conditions I need to look for the class that contains isOverflown, but I’m not sure what the best method might be. Any suggestions for looking for accessing class name

```
  it('render', () => {
  const wrapper= mount(<ScrollArea  {...props} />)
  expect(wrapper.find('a').props().className).toBe('isOverflown')
```

getting error:

```
expected: isOverflown

received: ScrollArea__scrollArea___HQjeV isOverflown  TMwDC
```

console.log(wrapper.debug()) results in

```
  <Memo() title="title" href="link address">
    <StyledComponent onClick={[undefined]} href="link address" target="_blank" disabled={[undefined]} forwardedComponent={{...}} forwardedRef={{...}}>
      <a className="ScrollArea__scrollArea___HQjeV isOverflown  TMwDC" onClick={[undefined]} href="link address" target="_blank" disabled={[undefined]}>
        title
      </a>
    </StyledComponent>
```

How to achieve this, thanks for the help

Comment: You could use [`toContain`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tocontainitem), or [`hasClass`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/hasClass.html).

Comment: @jonrsharpe expect(wrapper.find('a').hasClass('isOverflown')).to.equal(true)
is this the one you are asking to look into

Comment: `.to.equal` is not Jest's matcher syntax, but otherwise yes.

Comment: Is that not possible to get that class name using find() .className??

Comment: What do you mean *"is that not possible"*? Yes, of course you could use e.g. `.find(".isOverflown")` if you wanted to.

Comment: Please give a [mre]. Are you using both `.find("." + className)` *and* `.hasClass(className)`? That seems redundant. Either test that you can find the element by the class *or* that if you find the element by another means it has the class you expect.

Comment: @ jonrsharpe  console.log("****",output.find('a').hasClass('isOverflown')) ---hasClass” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead

Comment: Then `output.find('a')` doesn't find any nodes, but without more information I can't tell you why.

Comment: <Memo() title="title" href="link address">
      <styled.a onClick={[undefined]} href="link address" target="_blank" disabled={[undefined]}>
        <StyledComponent onClick={[undefined]} href="link address" target="_blank" disabled={[undefined]} forwardedComponent={{...}} forwardedRef={{...}}>
          <a className="ScrollArea__scrollArea___HQjeV isOverflown  TMwDC" onClick={[undefined]} href="link address" target="_blank" disabled={[undefined]}>
            title
          </a>
        </StyledComponent>

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe i have added some more console output

Comment: But you're not showing your latest code or the error message. Read that help article.

Comment: You're still showing `.toBe('isOverflown')`, which is obviously not going to work. Give a [mre] **of your current code**.

Comment: Ya , I agree but i need a right answer what should i put instead of toBe('isOverflown') else
Please give me answer which has  toContain, or hasClass

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(wrapper.find('a').debug()).toContain('yourCalssNAme').
```

If you don't use this class' name as a string anywhere else in the component, this would be a safety check.

```
wrapper.debug() (from enzymejs documention)
```

> Returns an HTML-like string of the wrapper for debugging purposes. Useful to print out to the console when tests are not passing when you expect them to.

In this case, it would also print your class name so if you want to make sure the component includes it - use my code above.

Comment: @Archana try it with the latest edit please

Comment: It initially contained multiple typos and now appears to be asserting on the whole HTML-like debug string, which is hardly robust - what if that class name appears somewhere else in the rendered content?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you please be more specific

Comment: @Archana well, as a trivial example, what if it renders `<a class="wrongName" href="https://example.com">rightName</a>`? The test passes even though the `rightName` is *not even a class*. Just checking that the test appears *somewhere* in the rendered DOM does **not** give a decent level of confidence the software is behaving correctly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is that edited question is not sufficient to get the answer

Comment: @double-beep Thank you for commenting. Please let me know what you think of the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
expect(wrapper.exists('a.isOverflown')).to.equal(true);
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe what do you say about this answer